# Add or remove rows in a dataframe based on pickerInput() selections in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have the dataframe below:

```
And<-structure(list(`Trvl mon` = structure(c(1546300800, 1546300800, 
                                             1548979200, 1548979200, 1551398400, 1551398400, 1554076800, 1554076800, 
                                             1556668800, 1556668800, 1559347200, 1559347200, 1561939200, 1561939200, 
                                             1564617600, 1564617600, 1567296000, 1567296000, 1569888000, 1569888000, 
                                             1572566400, 1572566400, 1575158400, 1575158400, 1577836800, 1577836800, 
                                             1580515200, 1580515200, 1583020800, 1583020800, 1585699200, 1585699200, 
                                             1588291200, 1588291200, 1590969600, 1590969600, 1593561600, 1593561600, 
                                             1596240000, 1596240000, 1598918400, 1598918400, 1601510400, 1601510400, 
                                             1604188800, 1604188800, 1606780800, 1606780800, 1609459200, 1609459200, 
                                             1612137600, 1612137600, 1614556800, 1614556800, 1617235200, 1617235200, 
                                             1619827200, 1619827200, 1622505600, 1622505600), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                                       "POSIXt")), month = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 
                                                                                                                                             7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 
                                                                                                                                             5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 1, 1, 2, 
                                                                                                                                             2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6), year = c(2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
                                                                                                                                                                                  2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
                                                                                                                                                                                  2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 
                                                                                                                                                                                  2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
                                                                                                                                                                                  2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
                                                                                                                                                                                  2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
                                                                                                                                                                                  2021), `yyyy-mm` = c(201901, 201901, 201902, 201902, 201903, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                       201903, 201904, 201904, 201905, 201905, 201906, 201906, 201907, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                       201907, 201908, 201908, 201909, 201909, 201910, 201910, 201911, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                       201911, 201912, 201912, 202001, 202001, 202002, 202002, 202003, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                       202003, 202004, 202004, 202005, 202005, 202006, 202006, 202007, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                       202007, 202008, 202008, 202009, 202009, 202010, 202010, 202011, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                       202011, 202012, 202012, 202101, 202101, 202102, 202102, 202103, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                       202103, 202104, 202104, 202105, 202105, 202106, 202106), `ctry-cd` = c("AD", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "AF", "AD", "AF", "AD", "AF", "AD", "AF", "AD", "AF", "AD", "AF", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "AD", "AF", "AD", "AF", "AD", "AF", "AD", "AF", "AD", "AF", "AD", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "AF", "AD", "AF", "AD", "AF", "AD", "AF", "AD", "AF", "AD", "AF", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "AD", "AF", "AD", "AF", "AD", "AF", "AD", "AF", "AD", "AF", "AD", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "AF", "AD", "AF", "AD", "AF", "AD", "AF", "AD", "AF", "AD", "AF", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "AD", "AF", "AD", "AF"), country = c("Andorra", "Afghanistan", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "Andorra", "Afghanistan", "Andorra", "Afghanistan", "Andorra", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "Afghanistan", "Andorra", "Afghanistan", "Andorra", "Afghanistan", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "Andorra", "Afghanistan", "Andorra", "Afghanistan", "Andorra", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "Afghanistan", "Andorra", "Afghanistan", "Andorra", "Afghanistan", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "Andorra", "Afghanistan", "Andorra", "Afghanistan", "Andorra", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "Afghanistan", "Andorra", "Afghanistan", "Andorra", "Afghanistan", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "Andorra", "Afghanistan", "Andorra", "Afghanistan", "Andorra", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "Afghanistan", "Andorra", "Afghanistan", "Andorra", "Afghanistan", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "Andorra", "Afghanistan", "Andorra", "Afghanistan", "Andorra", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "Afghanistan", "Andorra", "Afghanistan", "Andorra", "Afghanistan", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "Andorra", "Afghanistan", "Andorra", "Afghanistan", "Andorra", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "Afghanistan", "Andorra", "Afghanistan"), special = c(NA_character_, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
                    `ctry cnt` = c(46405, 47584, 77984, 49383, 44869, 35978, 
                                   81882, 22660, 76750, 91934, 86015, 99057, 73269, 73847, 4439, 
                                   33573, 1689, 1043, 52308, 22372, 37636, 53904, 55483, 58052, 
                                   22306, 64626, 21552, 5917, 74636, 30141, 55701, 14410, 14099, 
                                   13611, 84315, 79925, 15568, 53504, 35756, 56814, 73793, 80979, 
                                   83296, 11295, 47910, 95974, 97970, 83357, 57557, 59583, 67634, 
                                   89220, 20743, 43591, 97418, 92735, 8878, 34230, 82116, 88779
                    )), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                    ))
```

and I want every time I select a country to be displayed in the plotly graph. With the way I have built it I can display only one country per time. How can I create my dataframe in order to include all selected countries?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(xts)
library(shinyWidgets)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    pickerInput(
      inputId = "p2",
      label = "",
      choices = c("Andorra","Afghanistan"),
      multiple = T,
      selected="Andorra",
      options = pickerOptions(`actions-box` = TRUE,
                              title = "Country",
                              selectedTextFormat = 'static'
      )
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    column(width = 8,
           fluidRow(
             shinydashboard::box(width = 12,  plotlyOutput(outputId = "detailed_plot_2", height = "600px" ))
           )
           
           
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$detailed_plot_2<-renderPlotly({
    And<-subset(And,country%in%input$p2)
    And<-And[,c(1,8)]
    And$`Trvl mon`<-as.Date(And$`Trvl mon`)
    andts<-ts(And)
    andts <- xts::xts(andts[, -1], as.Date(as.numeric(andts[,1]),origin = '1970-01-01'))
    fit = arima(andts, order = c(4, 1, 1))
    
    
    pred = predict(fit, n.ahead = 6)
    predata<-as.data.frame(pred$pred)
    predata$Date<-as.Date(c("2021-07-01","2021-08-01","2021-09-01","2021-10-01","2021-11-01","2021-12-01"))
    colnames(predata)[1]<-"ctry cnt"
    predata$country<-input$p2
    plot_ly(predata,
            x = ~Date, 
            y = ~`ctry cnt`,
            text = ~`Date`,
            color = ~country,
            customdata = predata$country) %>%
      add_trace(
        type = 'scatter',
        mode = 'lines+markers',
        hovertemplate = paste("%{customdata}",
                              "%{y}", 
                              "<extra></extra>",
                              sep = "\n"),
        hoveron = 'points') %>%
      
      layout(font = list(color = '#a2a2a2'),title=list(text="Country Count by month",x = 0),
             xaxis = list(rangeslider = list(),fixedrange = FALSE,title="",showgrid = FALSE,tickangle = 45
             ),
             showlegend=T,
             yaxis = list(rangeslider = list(),fixedrange = FALSE,title="",showgrid = FALSE,showline=T),
             hovermode = "x unified",
             hoverlabel = "none",
             legend = list(itemclick = F, itemdoubleclick = F))
  })
 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the split-apply-combine approach to apply arima.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(xts)
library(shinyWidgets)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    pickerInput(
      inputId = "p2",
      label = "",
      choices = c("Andorra","Afghanistan"),
      multiple = T,
      selected="Andorra",
      options = pickerOptions(`actions-box` = TRUE,
                              title = "Country",
                              selectedTextFormat = 'static'
      )
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    column(width = 8,
           fluidRow(
             shinydashboard::box(width = 12,  plotlyOutput(outputId = "detailed_plot_2", height = "600px" ))
           )
           
           
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$detailed_plot_2<-renderPlotly({
    And<-subset(And,country%in%input$p2)
    And<-And[,c(1,6, 8)]
    And$`Trvl mon`<-as.Date(And$`Trvl mon`)
    And %>%
      group_split(country) %>%
      map_df(~{
        andts <- xts::xts(.x[[3]], as.Date(as.numeric(.x[[1]]),origin = '1970-01-01'))
        fit = arima(andts, order = c(4, 1, 1))
        pred = predict(fit, n.ahead = 6)
        predata<-as.data.frame(pred$pred)
        predata$Date<-as.Date(c("2021-07-01","2021-08-01","2021-09-01","2021-10-01","2021-11-01","2021-12-01"))
        colnames(predata)[1]<-"ctry cnt"
        predata$country<- .x$country[1]
        predata
      }) -> result
    
    
    

    plot_ly(result,
            x = ~Date, 
            y = ~`ctry cnt`,
            text = ~`Date`,
            color = ~country,
            customdata = result$country) %>%
      add_trace(
        type = 'scatter',
        mode = 'lines+markers',
        hovertemplate = paste("%{customdata}",
                              "%{y}", 
                              "<extra></extra>",
                              sep = "\n"),
        hoveron = 'points') %>%
      
      layout(font = list(color = '#a2a2a2'),title=list(text="Country Count by month",x = 0),
             xaxis = list(rangeslider = list(),fixedrange = FALSE,title="",showgrid = FALSE,tickangle = 45
             ),
             showlegend=T,
             yaxis = list(rangeslider = list(),fixedrange = FALSE,title="",showgrid = FALSE,showline=T),
             hovermode = "x unified",
             hoverlabel = "none",
             legend = list(itemclick = F, itemdoubleclick = F))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]